# Bug no sales_flat_order_item

Tags: mysql, magento, product, radix

Checking the table sales_flat_order_item noticed that i have records of products with two different IDs, for example:
Product 1.
ID shown in the Backend: 148
ID recorded in the table: 158 and 148 times.
I think there was some kind of error in import product list, because imported from a previous site.
Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Table `sales_flat_order_item` contains information about purchased products. It doesn't refer to product catalog.

Comment: Got it, I can change the ID of the products in sales_flat_order_item? Leaving the products with the same SKU and ID?